# Unable to disable dragable gesture on Spin Wheel in flutter by David Anaya

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am implementing the **flutter_spinning_wheel 1.1.0** by *David Anaya*. I have implemented the spin using button click and I want to disable the default draggable gesture i.e. used to spin the wheel. Can anyone please help me how can I disable the draggable gesture on the spin wheel.

Below is the link for **flutter_spinning_wheel 1.1.0** plugin:

> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinning_wheel

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: why not disable any gesture after the scrolling started?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. If you have gone through the plugin documentation correctly then you will figure it out that I am not using any gestures to spin the wheel as that is its default behavior. In my case, I have created one function and pass it in the property called **shouldStartOrStop** that is responsible to start or stop the wheel (This is achieved using on a button click).  But the wheel is also spin when we drag it with help of fingers and I didn't find any solution to disable this feature in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I found a solution to this by myself.
If we go to the above-mentioned plugin documentation correctly then we will find a **Gesture detector** in *spinning_wheel.dart* class.

**Open your plugin class (spinning_wheel.dart)**

Just commented the below code that I have shared and then rebuild your app again. Your draggable gesture will be disabled. **(This is just for those who are seeking to spin the wheel using a button)**

```
class SpinningWheel extends StatefulWidget {
-------
}

class _SpinningWheelState extends State<SpinningWheel>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

------------
------------

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: widget.height,
      width: widget.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
//          GestureDetector(
//            onPanUpdate: _moveWheel,
//            onPanEnd: _startAnimationOnPanEnd,
//            onPanDown: (_details) => _stopAnimation(),
            //child:
            AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: _animation,
                child: Container(child: widget.image),
                builder: (context, child) {
                  _updateAnimationValues();
                  widget.onUpdate(_currentDivider);
                  return Transform.rotate(
                    angle: _initialSpinAngle + _currentDistance,
                    child: child,
                  );
                }),
          //),
          widget.secondaryImage != null
              ? Positioned(
                  top: topSecondaryImage,
                  left: leftSecondaryImage,
                  child: Container(
                    height: heightSecondaryImage,
                    width: widthSecondaryImage,
                    child: widget.secondaryImage,
                  ))
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

-----------
-----------
}
```